# Updating other Tables Automatically in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am learning Flask/SQLAlchemy and am trying to create a simple database. Some of the tables can be computed based on the other tables, but I'm not quite sure where/how to add that logic.

As a simplified problem, let's say there are three tables in this database (* is primary key, ** is foreign key):

```
User: | id* | name | username | password |
Transactions: | id* | user_id** | date | quantity | value |
Holdings: | id* | user_id** | date | holdings |
```

I am then using `flask-admin` to manually add an entry in the `Transactions` table. Let's suppose that we added the entry:
`user_id = 1, date = '5/31/2022', quantity = 10, value = $30`.

The goal here is that when this entry is added, Flask knows to automatically add another entry to the `Holdings` table by calculating some Python function. Let's suppose that `Holdings.holdings = Transactions.quantity * Transactions.value`, so that the goal is to automatically add the following entry: `user_id = 1, date = '5/31/2022', holdings = $300` to the `Holdings` table.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

In Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
# Flask boilerplate code, register blueprints, etc

db = SQLAlchemy()

# Database Models

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

class Transactions(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User')

    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    transaction = db.Column(db.Float())

class Holdings(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User')

    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    holdings = db.Column(db.Float())


db.init_app(app)
```

---

**Update**
This is largely based on the logic of @jorzel answer, with some changes as I forgot to mention I am using `flask_sqlalchemy`.

```
@event.listens_for(Transactions, 'after_insert')
def UpdateHoldings(mapper, connection, transaction):

    # Adding new entry
    holdings_val = transaction.quantity * transaction.value
    holdings = Holdings(user_id = transaction.user_id,
                        date = transaction.date,
                        holdings = holdings_val)
    db.session.add( holdings )

    # (Not mentioned in OP, but if we want to update some table)
    # ( And assuming this table does not have date field )
    another_tbl = AnotherTable.__table__
    connection.execute(
        another_tbl.update().where(another_tbl.c.user_id == 
        transaction.user_id).values( holdings = holdings_val )
    )
```

Note: For some reason, `db.session.commit` throws a `This session is closed` error. However not including it seems to work.

Comment: You may try sqlalchemy events: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/events.html

Comment: That seems exactly what I need, but I'm having some trouble following the documentation as I am very new to SQLalchemy. Do you have any suggested tutorials on using Events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a simple example using sqlalchemy event `after_insert` handling.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import event, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from tutorial.models import Transaction, Holding, User

DB_URI = "sqlite://"

engine = create_engine(DB_URI)
metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


@contextmanager
def transaction_scope(session):
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
        raise


def get_session(bind):
    Session = sessionmaker(bind)
    return Session()


@event.listens_for(Transaction, 'after_insert')
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    with get_session(connection) as session:
        with transaction_scope(session):
            transaction = target
            holding = Holding(
                user_id=transaction.user_id, 
                holdings=transaction.value * transaction.quantity, 
                date=transaction.date
            )
            session.add(holding)

def add_user(session) -> int:
    with transaction_scope(session):
        user = User(name='Test', username='test', password='secret')
        session.add(user)
        session.flush()
    return user.id

def tutorial_after_insert(with_raise=False):
    with get_session(engine) as session:
        user_id = add_user(session)
        with transaction_scope(session):
            transaction = Transaction(
                quantity=10,
                value=11.2,
                user_id=user_id,
                date=datetime.utcnow()
            )
            session.add(transaction)
            session.flush()
            if with_raise:
                raise Exception('exception')

try:
    tutorial_after_insert(with_raise=False)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    with get_session(engine) as session:
        print(session.query(Holding).all())
        print(session.query(Transaction).all())
```

You will get following result if no exception is raised:

```py
[Holding(id=1, user_id=1, value=112.0, date=2022-06-01 08:27:26.307473)]
[Transaction(id=1, user_id=1, quantity=10, value=11.2, date=2022-06-01 08:27:26.307473)]
```

If an exception occurs, no record would be added.

Similar example I have added to this repo: https://github.com/jorzel/sqlalchemy-events-tutorial

Comment: Thanks! This has helped a lot and is working. I've made some small modifications to it as I was using `Flask-sqlalchemy` (forgot to mention in OP). 

Instead of the session-scoping, I have `db.session.add(holding)` where `db = flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy()`. For updating tables, I have `connection.execute( Holdings.__table__.update() #. etc`

Comment: I should probably change this event handling and do not use session. I have found in the docs that: `Operations that are not supported within these mapper-level persistence events include:

Session.add()

Session.delete()

Mapped collection append, add, remove, delete, discard, etc.

Mapped relationship attribute set/del events, i.e. someobject.related = someotherobject

The reason the Connection is passed is that it is encouraged that simple SQL operations take place here, directly on the Connection, such as incrementing counters or inserting extra rows within log tables`